# How to create correctly a gtfs file

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, gtfs

I've created all the required txt files to create the gtfs file.
I would like to know if there is some proper way to create the file staring from the collection of txt.

I tried compressing the directory where the file are and then change the extension of the file but the result is an empty feed with gtfs_kit.